# Hist3 Plotting and Axes Range

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, histogram

I'm plotting a 3-D histogram with MATLAB and it's working pretty ok, except for the different axes ranges. I'd like them to be defined in a way, where equal value pairs lie on the bisecting line.

My code looks like this (more or less "stolen" from the `hist3` MATLAB example):

```
[vec_voxel_ids, vec_dose_values_reference, vec_dose_values_control] = ...
    textread('_BOOSTINT_voxel_data.txt', '%u %u %u');
mat_dose_values = [vec_dose_values_reference, vec_dose_values_control];
hist3(mat_dose_values, [100, 100]);
xlabel('Dose Reference');
ylabel('Dose Control');
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'opengl');
set(get(gca,'child'), 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'CDataMode', 'auto');
```

This is how it looks:
[image: histogram]

Comment: Can you be more precise with your question and what you are trying? Are your trying to adjust the axis limits with `axis`? What do you mean by "equal value pairs lie on the bisecting line"? Also, the code you supplied gives a 3-D view by default, I think you're missing a call to `view(2)` or something similar to obtain an image like the one you provided.

Comment: I have two vectors with values from 0-1000 which I combine to a nx2 matrix. if both values at the same index are the same, they shall lie on the bisecting line. in the image, this is not the case. this code I provided is the only thing I did to obtain the image above.

Comment: Of course I changed the camera angle to only view a 2D projection of the 3d histogram, sorry

Comment: I still don't know what you mean exactly by "the bisecting line". Is this the `Y = X` line with slope 1 that goes through the origin? Is the issue that each of your boxes (or rectangular prisms in 3-D) aren't centered on the values that they correspond to, but rather are positioned at the lower left corner?

Comment: Also, in cases like this, it's a lot easier for people to help (and see the problem at hand) if you provide simple example that is runnable. I imagine that you could better illustrate your issue with a tiny set of "dummy" data and code that creates a low resolution `hist3`.

Comment: Yes, next time provide a SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to reposition the bins to align their centers the ticks and also choose the range of the bin values you can use `hist3`'s `'edges'` option (similar to that in `histc`):

```
data = 500+5*randn(1e3,2);           % dummy data
d = 1;                               % width for x and y bins
x = 480:d:520;                       % range for x bins
y = x;                               % use same range for y bins, can be different
hist3(data, 'edges', {x-d/2,y-d/2}); % subtract half bin width to center bins
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'opengl');
set(get(gca,'child'), 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'CDataMode', 'auto');
view(2)
axis equal
axis([478 522 478 522])
grid minor
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
```

This example produces something like this:
[image: hist3 output]

Note, that this is a re-binning of your data so your output may look slightly different compared to before. The bins have been shifted to align their centers and the histogram recalculated.

Comment: ok, that was helpful. I added the two lines "axis equal" and 
"axis([x1 y1 x2 y2])" and the result is as I expect it to be. Is this itself a re-binning of data? In my understanding this is just re-positioning the bins.

Comment: Glad I figured it out. At least with your sample code you were auto-binning -just asking for 100-by-100 bins. In this case `hist3` mimics `hist`'s behavior in terms of how the bins are positioned rather than that of `histc`. Type `edit hist3` and check out the code around line 164 if you want details. So, yes, the location of the bin edges will be in slightly different locations.

Comment: By the way, in my code, the command `hist3(data, 'edges', {x-d/2,y-d/2});` could be replaced with `hist3(data, {x,y});` to use the `'Ctrs'` parameter. However, under the hood `hist3` uses the `'edges'` parameter natively and makes a call to `hictc`. If you know what you want and what you have, it makes sense to explicitly specify the edges of your bins.

Comment: The function `hist3` has some serious fenceposting issues: You would expect that for `n` bins you need to supply `n+1` edges. This is not true for `hist3`, which automatically creates another edge at the high end (line 202 in the source code)...